# Collection was modified; command separated string into list

Tags: c#

I have a comma separate string to pass, to be able to get the file to a directory, Below is the code. This error is shown when using string split then convert into the list. can you tell me what part of the error is in my code?

sample value:

- StudentList ="Image01.jpg,Image02.jpg"

  ```
  public FileResult DownloadZipFile(string StudentList)
     {

        var fileName = string.Format("{0}_ImageFiles.zip", DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "_1");
        var tempOutPutPath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Assets/Student_ID")) + fileName;

        using (ZipOutputStream s = new ZipOutputStream(System.IO.File.Create(tempOutPutPath)))
        {
           s.SetLevel(9); 

           byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];


           List<string> stringList = StudentList.Split(',').ToList();

           foreach (string str in stringList)
           {

              stringList.Add(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Student_ID/" + str));

           }


           for (int i = 0; i < stringList.Count; i++)
           {
              ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(stringList[i]));
              entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
              entry.IsUnicodeText = true;
              s.PutNextEntry(entry);

              using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(stringList[i]))
              {
                 int sourceBytes;
                 do
                 {
                    sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    s.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
                 } while (sourceBytes > 0);
              }
           }
           s.Finish();
           s.Flush();
           s.Close();

        }

        byte[] finalResult = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempOutPutPath);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempOutPutPath))
           System.IO.File.Delete(tempOutPutPath);

        if (finalResult == null || !finalResult.Any())
           throw new Exception(String.Format("No Files found with Image"));

        return File(finalResult, "application/zip", fileName);

     }
  ```

Comment: Why are you splitting the student list, then iterating over it and adding back into the same list?

Comment: You are trying to modify a collection in your foreach statement, line   `stringList.Add(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Student_ID/" + str));` . It's the same collection that you are looping on, that is not allowed for obvious reasons.

Comment: That "Collection was modified" exception originated from a particular line in your application (see its StackTrace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your foreach loop. You iterate through the list, but while doing so, you modify the collection. Thats causing the error. One solution to solve this, is to create a temporary dummy List:

```
List<string> stringList = StudentList.Split(',').ToList();
List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
foreach (string str in stringList)
   {
       tempList .Add(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Student_ID/" + str));
   }
stringList = tempList;
```

An alternative solution without a second list, would be to use a classic for-loop:

```
List<string> stringList = StudentList.Split(',').ToList();
for(int i = 0; i < stringList.Count; i++)
    {
       stringList [i] = "~/Assets/Student_ID/" + stringList [i];
    }
```